# How to push key & value in an array without quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an empty array. I'm trying to push key value pairs into the array but it will goes with quotes. How can I send it without quotes?

Here is my code:

```
var Array_1 = [];

Array_1.push("{ " + configJsonArray[k].name +  ":" + "'" + customerData[j][L].value + "'" + ", type:" + "'" + configJsonArray[k].type + "'" + " }");

// configJsonArray[k].name -- key from another array

// customerData[j][L].value --  value from another array
```

**what I'm expecting result is** 
[{ total:'30', type:'cart' },{ customerId:'4', type:'info' }]

**result which i getting** 
["{ total:'30', type:'cart' }","{ customerId:'4', type:'info' }"]

Comment: You're pushing a string, of course you'll get quotes... (`JSON.parse`)

Comment: @tymeJV He knows that. He's asking how to push an object with dynamic property names.

Comment: This is because you are pushing a string into an array, when you print the array it is shown as a string in quotes.

Comment: @blex yes you are right.

Comment: @tymeJV When i try to push the static values like Array_1.push({test:'baskar',number:'asm'}); its working fine but I'm getting issue with dynamic values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a string and not an object. You can create the object and push that in to the Array.

```
var Array_1 = [];
var temp = {};
temp[configJsonArray[k].name] = customerData[j][L].value;
temp["type"] = configJsonArray[k].type;
Array_1.push(temp);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I got the expected result through your code

Answer (score 2):

You want to push an object, not a string (albeit a string of an object)

```
ar Array_1 = [];

var objToPush = {};
objToPush[configJsonArray[k].name] = customerData[j] [L].value;

Array_1.push(objToPush);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing a string, which won't be evaluated magically.

Instead of a string you should use an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

In ES6 you can use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to set its property name to the value of your variable:

```js
var Array_1 = [{
  [configJsonArray[k].name]: customerData[j][L].value,
  type: configJsonArray[k].type
});
```